# cd to multiple directories in a shell script

Tags: shell

I am making a script named `Big_script.sh` to access two directories called `A` and `B`, inside them i need to access three directories called `A1`, `A2`, `A3`; `B1`, `B2`, `B3` (respectively). Once in there, i need the script to run another script with `sh small_script.sh`.

Is it possible to do something like this in  `Big_script`:

```
cd */*
sh small_script.sh
```

or is there any way to do that in a shell script or in python that could help? because it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `cd` to more than one directory at a time (so you need to come back to the original directory, if the path to `cd` is relative). It is not a limitation of the shell but a property of unix [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (so coding in some other language like Python or C won't change much); they each have only 
*one* current directory (and the shell runs the [chdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html) system call for its `cd` builtin)

You might consider computing the full path (using [realpath(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html)) of every directory, and storing that path in some shell variable. Then you could `cd` in a loop.

Some shells have a *stack* of directories, which you could manipulate with `pushd` & `popd`. In that case, you might code

```
for d in */* ; do
  pushd "$d"
  sh small_script
  popd
done
```

You need to be sure that the [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) expansion of `*/*` gives only directories. With `zsh` you might code `*/*(/)` to expand only directories. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) & [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) & [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

If your shell don't have `pushd` you could try

```
for d in $(realpath */*); do
  cd "$d" && sh small_script.sh
done
```

or using a subshell

```
for d in */*; do
  (cd "$d" && exec small_script.sh)
done
```

See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77077/how-do-i-use-pushd-and-popd-commands) for more about `pushd` & `popd`

Notice that if you do `cd a/b` followed later by `cd e/f`  the shell is trying to go (for the second `cd`)  into the `a/b/e/f` directory (which probably do not exist) because `e/f` is a relative path (so interpreted in the context of the previous current directory `a/b`). You might want `cd a/b` followed by `cd ../../e/f` ...

Take time to understand why `cd` needs to be a shell builtin. Perhaps read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

See also [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html). It might be more useful (with its `-exec` action).

BTW, it could be simpler to change your `small_script` to accept as argument the directory in which it should go. Then that script might start with `cd "$1"`.

Comment: Do what? Whatever language you use, a unix process has only *one* current directory.

Comment: You need to read a lot more about Linux. I recommend to spend a few days reading http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ; you have a very messy idea about Unix processes

Comment: I'd suggest `(cd "$d" && exec sh small_script.sh)` to be demonstrating good practices -- don't want to fail with directories with names containing spaces, nor to run a command in the wrong directory if the `cd` fails. And the `exec` in this case counterbalances the performance impact of the subshell created by the parens.

Comment: You should try to understand them first by reading a lot more.